# nginx: limit execution of .php files only to certain directories

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Right now my nginx is configured to redirect php file requests from *all directories* to php5-fpm as follows:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

How can I limit php files execution to only a few predefined directories, like 'dir1', 'dir2' and 'dir3', while access to php files in other directories should be rejected or ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location ~ ^/dir1/subdir1/.+\.php(/|$) {
                include php.conf;
        }
location ~ ^/dir2/subdir2/.+\.php(/|$) {
                include php.conf;
        }
location ~ ^/dir3/subdir3/.+\.php(/|$) {
                include php.conf;
        }
```

Contents of php.conf

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
```

Comment: Thank you! 1. Why (/|$) at the end? 2. Why did you remove try_files $uri =404;?

Comment: `try_files` is used when you want to have a `catch_all` - i.e. if the requested file does not exist, use `index.php` or whatever you specify. You have specified =404 which effectively sends 404 error just like without `try_files`. The `(/|$)` means that the PHP extension will be cough even if your URL has a trailing slash.

Comment: 1. Will this allow also subdirectories? 2. How can I enable this for root / but without subdirectories?

Comment: This works with regular expressions - if your regular expression allows subfolders then yes, it will work. In the example above it will catch every PHP file below the initial path. For root only you can try `location ~ ^/[^/]+\.php$` but I have not tested this.